# How do I route the POST,PUT and GET to different business logic on Django-REST framework?

Tags: python, django, api, express, django-rest-framework

I have started working on django-rest framework.... I selected this framework because I wanted to integrate the same api's with a mobile application(android). I had done this before with nodeJs(Express) , I used to write GET,POST,PUT and DELETE request for the same url and write business logic in it. How do i implement the same with DjangoRest....

How do I route the PUT or POST request to business logic and give a response like I do in ExpressJs

Something like below:

module.exports = function (router) {

```
router.get('/demoEndPoint', function(req,res){
          /*business logic here
    res.send('hello world');
});
router.post('/demoEndPoint', function(req,res){
   /*business logic here
    res.send('hello world this Post Request');
});
router.put('/demoEndPoint', function(req,res){
          /*business logic here
    res.send('hello world put request');
});
```

};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create single api endpoint that handles different types of requests one should override the methods to implement custom logic. By default there are be `predefined functions for each http methods GET,PUT,POST,PATCH and DELETE`. Refer to the code block below for an example.

### urls

```
url(r'^api-endpoint/', apiView.as_view(), namespace='rest_framework')),
```

### views

```
class apiView(viewsets.viewset):
    def get(self, request):
        ...
    def post(self, request):
        ...
    def put(self, request):
        ...
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

> Try this,
>
> First create a Express application,

var express = require('express');
    var app = express();

> then call post method like this

```
app.post('/demoEndPoint', function (req, res) {
  res.send('POST request to homepage');
});
```